# Can GLSL use any other data structures like a map, queue, stack?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am working with mesh materials and I would like to be able to get them by ID, not using the array index. I didn't find anything to do with other data structures so if anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great, specifically to do with the c++ Type maps.

The reason why I need the material to be read in the shader with material ID is because I am doing deferred rendering and I am trying to avoid sending a texture for specular, ambient and diffused colours. Instead I store the material ID in the alpha of my normal texture and use that ID to find which material each fragment should use in the Phong lighting calculation. The problem is that I need to loop through the array of materials checking if the material ID from the array matches the material ID from the normal texture which is not ideal. I thought that if I could make the material ID the key needed to access the data, it would be a bit more efficient as I would not need a loop, just a lookup. I could possibly pass all materials in the right order and send it to my light program but that would mean I am passing in a bigger array because there are 29 unique meshes that reuse materials from an array of 7 materials. So that would mean I would be sending at least 29 materials instead of just 7.

Comment: Short answer: No. See the specification [GLSL - The OpenGL Shading Language 4.6](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf)

Comment: Why not store the index instead of the ID? Then no lookup will be needed.

Comment: To BDL, yes that seems like the best idea. I will implement that now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass arbitrary data to OpenGL, so you could send a structure with you data stored as a map, and implement in your shader the way to retrieve it. But you can't have templated class and recursion. So it will be much simpler than STL's map<>. You can't have pointers either. So behind your map there would just be a const array

Your question is too broad to answer precisely, but Usually, if you want to send material information, it should be part of the shader Data, I'm not sure why you would need to retrieve material once you're in the shader.